# In Ajax Image not uploading with other forms data,shows blank array in $_FILES

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to save image and other forms data with ajax, But Some problems facing while uploading image. Image is selected and Sent from js but in php $_FILES not getting this image its return blank

> IN js

```
     var datastr = 'productionstrategyno='+productionstrategyno+
'&manufacturingleadtime='+manufacturingleadtime;
     if (($("#item-master-image"))[0].files.length > 0) {
                                    file = ($("#item-master-image"))[0].files[0];
                                    datastr += '&images='+file;
                                }

                                $.ajax({
                                url: base_url+'ajax_response/item_master',
                                type: 'post',
                                data: datastr,
                                dataType: 'json',
                                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                                processData: false,  // do not process the data as url encoded params
                                success: function(json) {

                                    if(json.status="200"){
                                        msgalert(json.msg,"success");
                                        window.location.href=base_url+"master/listItem";
                                    }else{
                                        msgalert(json.msg,"danger");

                                    }
                                }
                                });
```

> It's send to php giving

```
isstandardmaterial:1
ismaintainbincard:1
images:[object File]
```

> In PHP

```
<?php print_r($_FILES['images']); ?>
```

It return blank array value

Comment: need to use `FormData` API to upload files using ajax. This is not hard to research

Comment: @charlietfl But i have other details also to send. which are creating dynamically in js

Comment: @charlietfl But i have other details also to send. which are creating dynamically in js. When i use `new FormData(this)` to send the form in `data` than `------WebKitFormBoundaryRYug9sTmsmSkmCRH--` sent in ajax form data